# Manipulating History.Back does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

In my Project I open a new page using

I use a parameter to tell the following page what is his parent.  (relative path) The JS-Code is the following:

```
function FillHistory() {  
    var parent = getUrlVars()["parent"];
    var currentUrl = $(location).attr('href');

    History.pushState({ state: 2 }, parent, parent);
    History.pushState({ state: 2 }, currentUrl, currentUrl);
}
```

(`getUrlVars` is a method to get the GET-parameters of that URL)

Now, When I click onto the `Back-Button` the address of the "`parent`"-URL is shown in the browser, but the current page just stays there.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
history.replaceState({value: 1, value2: X}, "title", "page.php");
```

Comment: If I do that, it reaches the wanted site when Clicking first on Back, and then on Forward

Comment: so you dont want it to return to parent site on forward button??

Comment: I do want to return to the site I entered (like page.php in your example) when clicking onto the back-button but that does NOT happen, when I click onto the back button, but after I click onto the forward button afterwards.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/history-api/ Have a go through it .. There is also a demo on this page ..Is this wat u want to achieve??